# How to plot quiver (current/wind arrows) plot on a basemap

Tags: models, mapping, python

and thank you for answering
I am trying to plot a [quiver plot](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200413150909/plot31.png) on a basemap (The basemap has to be a good quality map such as openstreetmap) and I can't find a way to do it.

There are some examples on the web of doing it with a package called mpl_toolkits which is now deprecated. Another option might be using geopandas and contextily. I was able to create a point plot but could not find a way to plot 3d plots (contour/contourf/pcolor).

Has anyone done it before?
Thanks again
Yair

Comment: The answer to your question is in the Basemap documentation: 
 https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html

Comment: and why do you want to plot a quiver plot in 3d at all?

Comment: By 3D I include somethinh like contours. How would I plot wind velocity/ direction other then by 3D plots?

Comment: And thank you for tbe reference, I didnt know the barbs plot

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913571/my-arrows-are-too-frequent-and-too-small-in-quiver

Comment: I was out of the office for a few days and came back this morning.
The  @Weiss suggestion were probably greate but they lead me to another question. I am not able to install basemap on anacondas (this is why I wrote it was deprecated in the original question). Does anyone know a good tutorial to how this is done?

Comment: I would use pip! However have a look at the basemap documentation! You can finde it for shure there

Comment: By now I am sure that I was right inthe original question. Basemap is now deprecated and replaced by cartopy. Hopefully I will past the code here in a few days